# How do I add numbers and spaces to my typing function in Python?

Tags: python

Considering that I just asked a question on here yesterday and received a helpful answer in 3 minutes, I have decided to ask another.
My type function (functions similarly to print, but types each character individually) now has the capability to accept multiple arguments. Now, however, I need it to accept numbers which is a problem because integers are not iterable. Therefore, I need a way to cleanly convert an int into an str within my function.
Also, I need a way to put spaces between each argument.

my current code is:

```
def type(*text):
  for string in text:
    for char in string:
      sys.stdout.write(char)
      sys.stdout.flush()
      time.sleep(0.05)
  print()
```

Applying a standard str() function yields brackets and single quotation marks around my input, is there any way to cleanly convert this?
Also, there is currently no spacing between arguments so an input of:

```
type("hello",name)
```

would produce an output of:
hello(insert name here)
I would also appreciate a way to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: For spaces, use `" ".join( *words, go, here*)` For converting an `int` to `str`, do `str(myint)`.

Comment: If you are wanting parameters to be `int`, you should show what you tried, and presumably you get an error, so you should show that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a space after each word like that :

```
import time
import sys

def type(*text):
    for string in text:
        for char in string:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.05)
        sys.stdout.write(" ")
    print()


name = "hugo"
type("hello", name)
```

Answer (score 2):

The name `type` is a Python [build-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type), so we better not to use this name for our own function.

```py
def type_char(*text):
    for string in text:
        # if string is not isinstance(string, str):
        #     string = str(string)
        # string += " "
        # just as @quamrana comment, the above logic can be
        # accomplished in a more concise way by this one-liner code
        string = str(string) + " "
        for char in string:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    print()


>>> type_char("hello", 5, "world")
hello 5 world 
>>> type_char("hello", 5.9, "world")
hello 5.9 world
```

Comment: You can just use: `string = str(string) + ' '` instead of using `isinstance()`